# Getting elements from string array returned by split method

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a method `splitThat` which does the following:

```
public static void splitThat(String newString){
    System.out.println
      (java.util.Arrays.toString(newString.split("\\s+")));
}
```

The method `split` returns a string array, but I do not know how to reach elements of the returned string array seperately. Example:

```
splitThat("Please help me");
```

This will return the array:

> [Please, help, me]

When I want to reach to the first element of the array, I can't simply use index, the compiler gives error messages and suggested fixes do not help. How I can do this?

Comment: You could start with returning that array from `splitThat()` and by being more specific than " the compiler gives error messages", e.g. _which_ error messages? _Where_?

Comment: It doesn't return the array, it prints it. If you wan to use the value, you must return it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This will return the array:

The `void` method you've written doesn't return anything. It only **prints** the array.

You might want to change your method to something like:

```
public static String[] splitThat(String newString){
    return newString.split("\\s+");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `splitThat` doesn't return anything. It just prints the array returned by the call to `split`. Change your method to return a `String[]` instead of printing the array if you want to access elements of that array.

```
public static String[] splitThat(String newString){
    return newString.split("\\s+");
}

...

String[] s = splitThat("Please help me");
if (s.length > 0)
    System.out.println(s[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Is Copy As You Want**

```
public class TwoD {
    public static String[] splitThat(String newString){
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(newString.split("\\s+")));

        String []temp = newString.split("\\s+");

        return  temp;

    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {


        //Use This
        for(String outputs:splitThat("Please help me")) {
            System.out.println(outputs);
        }

        //OR USE
        String []outputs2 = splitThat("Please help me");

        for(int i = 0;i < outputs2.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(outputs2[i]);
        }

    }

}
```